# Получение SMART в PHP

Tags: php, smart

Существует ли библиотека для получения данных SMART в PHP?

Если нет - как вообще их можно получить без использования специализированных программ? Например, средствами другого языка передать данные в PHP

Comment: Не помню как в винде, а в линуксе для доступа к s.m.a.r.t. - нужны админские права. Так что тут вопрос в том - где именно ты хочешь считывать смарт. Если на севрере на котором будет крутиться скрипт - то сложностей возникнуть не должно, но админ будет недоволен. Если на клиенте - сначала надо стать рутом.

Comment: Задача: сделать сервис, который будет отслеживать состояние диска,- установленного в сервере,- по информации из SMART, и предупреждать о возможном появлении проблемы в панели администратора. Для этого нужно эти данные как-то получить, что и вызывает сложность. С правами проблем нет

Comment: На сервере должны быть встроенные средства диагностики винта или через raid-контроллер или через софт к материнке. И по идее про плохое железо должен уметь рапортовать zabbix и прочие nagios. Если хочется написать свой велосипед - смотри в сторону `smartmontools`.

Comment: Попытаюсь, спасибо.